# Call methods/functions in @Value-annotation

Tags: spring-boot

In a projection object, I am trying to introduce a field `isOwner` whenever the ID of the currently logged in user equals the user-ID on the respective record/element.

So, it's basically just the following:

```java
public interface Quiz {

    @Value("#{userUtil.equalsLoggedInUser(target.appUser)}")
    Boolean isOwner();

}
```

For this I have a `UtilService` which fetches the logged in user-record and does the necessary comparison like so:

```java
@Service
public class UserUtil {

    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserUtil( AppUserRepository appUserRepository) {
        this.appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
    }

    public AppUserEntity getLoggedInAppUserEntity() {
        String uid = ServiceUtil.getUidFromPrincipal();
        return this.appUserRepository.findUserByFirebaseUuid(uid)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid or unknown \"uid\"."));
    }

    public Boolean equalsLoggedInUser(AppUserEntity appUserEntity) {
        return Objects.equals(appUserEntity.getId(), this.getLoggedInAppUserEntity().getId());
    }
}
```

As well as

```java
@Configuration
public class UtilBeans {
    @Bean
    public UserUtil getUserUtil(AppUserRepository appUserRepository) {
        return new UserUtil(appUserRepository);
    }
}
```

I'm confident that this can be done cleaner and/or more efficient but for now I just want it to work.

#### The Error

Running the code, the error I am getting indicates, that `userUtil` cannot be found:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: EL1008E: Property or field 'userUtil' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.data.projection.SpelEvaluatingMethodInterceptor$TargetWrapper' - maybe not public or not valid?]

I'm not sure how I can the `UserUtil` servie in SPEL. I've also tried to define a static-version of the `UserUtil`

```java
@Value("#{T(server.service.UserUtil).equalsLoggedInUser(target.appUser)}")
Boolean isOwner();
```

which ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please use either

```
@Configuration
public class UtilBeans {
    @Bean
    public UserUtil userUtil(AppUserRepository appUserRepository) {
        return new UserUtil(appUserRepository);
    }
}
```

or

```
@Value("#{getUserUtil.equalsLoggedInUser(target.appUser)}")
```